# Volatility - ISF Creation - Get kernel debug info

Tags: linux, kernel, debug-symbols, computer-forensics, volatility

Currently facing problems while trying to create an ISF Profile for Volatility 3 (for Linux). I want to get the debug kernel, but whatever I'm trying (for whichever Linux I'm using, so far Ubuntu or Debian) does not work.

I'm trying to get [this](https://volatility3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/symbol-tables.html#mac-or-linux-symbol-tables) to work, I already tried downloading the according [kernel]-dbgsym package with

```
apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r)-dbgsym
```

which fails (even when adding the keyring for dbgsym). I'm trying to get the debug info for Ubuntu 20.04 or newer (or any other newer Linux Distribution), but whatever I'm trying to load, nothing shows up in

```
/usr/src
```

or

```
/usr/lib/debug
```

as there is no /boot/-Folder.
I also tried the [volatility3 symbol creator](https://github.com/kevthehermit/volatility_symbols), but that didn't help either because it could not find any packages. Do the debug packages for newer distros even exist, or am I just extremely blind?

I need any way to create an ISF-Profile from scratch, and it feels like I'm missing something simple.
Does anyone have an idea? Thanks in advance!